# How to disable Caret Blinking in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm running Eclipse on Windows 7 and I want to disable blinking of cursor in text editor.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way to do this within Eclipse. However, you can do it at the Operating System Level:

**Control Panel > Keyboard Properties > Speed Tab >** Drag the slider for **Cursor blink rate** to the far left ("None") > Click **OK**.

[image: keyboardProperties]

The change is immediately effective in Eclipse (no need to restart anything), but be aware that it also affects other applications such as Notepad, Wordpad and Internet Explorer.

However, NetBeans and Opera were unaffected; their cursors continued to blink.

Comment: Yes thank you for this solution. I even wrote a trivial program utilizing win api's "SetCaretBlinkTime()" to quickly switch between blinking/non-blinking cursor but it's just a clumsy workaround

Comment: @Alex On Win 7 moving the slider changes the **CursorBlinkRate** value under **Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop**, and it should be straightforward to create a program to do that. However, if I modify that Registry value directly using **regedit** (e.g. Set **CursorBlinkRate** to **-1** to prevent cursor blink) it does not work, so the slider action is clearly doing something else as well.

Comment: @Alex It looks like the explicit registry change for **CursorBlinkRate** is only effective after logging out, and then logging back in again.