# Intellij IDEA: how to changing blinking cursor to non-blinking?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have vim emulator turned on, which is the desired behavior; turning it off only changes the blinking, block cursor into a blinking, non-block cursor.

Comment: I don't know whether it would necessarily impact Intellij IDEA, but you can turn off cursor blinking at the operating system level. [Here's how to do it on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233299/how-to-disable-caret-blinking-in-eclipse/49291724#49291724), which did turn off cursor blinking in Eclipse. Of course the risk with that approach is that even if does what you want, you may find that you also lose the blinking cursor in other apps where you still want it to blink.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks; consider this as a feature request?

Comment: Request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: You can turn off cursor blinking by going to Settings, Editor, General, Appearance and untick `Caret blinking`.

Answer (score 30):

> You can turn off cursor blinking by going to Settings, Editor, General, Appearance and untick `Caret blinking`

comment of @errikos above

Instead of navigating the settings with clicks only, you may also type `caret blink` into the search field. This way you let IDEA do the search work for you ;)

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to deactivate Vim Emulator. To do this go to Tools -> select Vim Emulator or press "ctrl+alt+v" as show below:

[image]

for more information follow this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-product-as-the-vim-editor.html

Answer (score 3):

Just go to file-->settings
type "blinking" in the searchbar.
untick Caret blinking(ms)
OK

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Settings -> General -> Appearance ->

Comment: And then do what?

Comment: Sorry Uncheck the "Use Block Caret" Box

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Settings->Editor->Appearance

You will see option named caret blinking :)

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can easily solved it. Just **uncheck** the caret blinking option.

[image]

[image]

[image]